# When I use Template Repeat how i know the Dom is ready

Tags: polymer

I using this template.

```
<template repeat = "{{cover in covers | keys}}">
   <div class ='item'>
     <img src="{{cover}}"></img>
    </div>
</template>
```

and in my polymer script

```
   domReady: function () {
      //aplly some css
    }
```

but when i debug the repeat is not over when the ready event is fired, so my css style changes is not happening.

Answer (score 3):

It would be best to know what CSS you're trying add. Typically, you should not try to manage the DOM of a `<template repeat>` yourself. Instead, tweak it with your data model. For example, you could dynamically apply the "show" class to the image based on a property it sets:

```
<template repeat = "{{cover in covers | keys}}">
  <div class ='item'>
     <img src="{{cover}}" class="{{ {show: cover.show} | tokenList }}">
  </div>
</template>
```

or do something similar by setting an inline `style`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, when the repeat finish I catch all items to put it in a slider with a jquery plugin this plugin put the styles